# Ruby access class inside "class << self" block

Tags: ruby, singleton, metaprogramming, self

How to access a class inside a `class << self` in Ruby? In the code sample, it's `SecondClass.func` which should be accessed.

```rb
class MainClass
  class << self

    class SecondClass
      def self.func
        p 'Hi!'
      end
    end

  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

It can be accessed like:

```rb
MainClass.singleton_class::SecondClass.func
```

Comment: Why did you delete your own answer which had solved it?

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to define a class in another class' singleton class, or is just a hypothetical question?

Answer (score 0):

It can be accessed like:

```rb
MainClass.singleton_class::SecondClass.func
```